# Error ejs is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-errors, ejs

I am using ejs, and I have the following code.

```
app.get('/profile/:name',function(req,res){
var data={
age: 29,
job:'ninja'
 };
 var ejsData={
data:data,
person:req.params.name
};
res.render('profile',ejsData);
});
```

With the following ejs file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{background: skyblue;font-family: verdana;color: #fff;padding: 
30px;}
h1{font-size: 48px;text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: 2px;text- 
align: center;}
p{font-size: 16px}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Profile Page <%= ejsData.person %></h1>
<p>The Age of the Person is <%= ejsData.data.age %> </p>
<p>He works as a <%= ejsData.data.job %> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

But I keep getting this error? What am i doing wroung?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reference the properties of the object you pass into the template rather than the object itself i.e.

```
<h1>Profile page <%= person %>
<p>The age of the person is <%= data.age %> </p>
...
```

If you want to reference the object directly then you need to pass that as a property instead

```
res.render("profile", { ejsData }):
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't pass in the object itself?

Comment: @akotch you can, I've shown you an example how you can do that. In terms of accessing the object the way you currently have, there's no way the template would know what to name it so for a consistent API it makes sense to expose the properties instead.

Comment: then how come it works if I pass ejsdata as a global object rather then local?

Comment: @akotch it's the same solution just masked differently, global vars are attached to the `global` object so in effect they become properties of that object. EJS most likely checks the local scope first (i.e. data passed via render) and then inspects the `global` object after.

Answer (score 0):

To match the ejs webpage quick start examples' convention, change your call to render to make ejsData a property of the passed in object:

```
res.render('profile', {ejsData: ejsData});
```

Possibly a little cleaner and maybe illustrates what is happening better, Simply remove the string "ejsData" from your ejs file (don't change the res.render call):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{background: skyblue;font-family: verdana;color: #fff;padding: 
30px;}
h1{font-size: 48px;text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: 2px;text- 
align: center;}
p{font-size: 16px}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Profile Page <%= person %></h1>
<p>The Age of the Person is <%= data.age %> </p>
<p>He works as a <%= data.job %> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

As your code stands in your post, ejsData is just the name of the variable passed into render.  The render function and the ejs template you give it won't know anything about that variable name (unless you make it a property of the object you pass in, as in the first example).

Comment: The how come if I were to pass ejsData as a global object it work? ejsData={
    data:data,
    person:req.params.name
  };

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.  Can you post that change with the entire JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

The probable cause for the issue may stem back to your routes. Go back to your routes and check whether your "ejsData" variable is placed on the right route. EJS is very specific.

For instance, if you place the "ejsData" variable in route "/a" and call it in route "/b", then it makes sense why EJS may not find the variable.